# how to print a "dictionary" of StringType() in the form of a table with pyspark

Tags: azure, pyspark, databricks

[image: image of the column of "dictionary" that I have and would like to turn it into a table of its own]

Hi,

The above column is part of a table that I am working with in Databricks. What I wish to do is to turn the "ecommerce" col into a table of its own. In this case, it means that I would have a new table with "detail", "products"....etc as columns. Currently "ecommerce" is a StringType.

I have tried using spark dictionary creation, tabulate and other methods but to no success.
The code that I have currently is

```
def ecommerce_wtchk_dlt():
    df = dlt.read_stream("wtchk_dlt")
    ddf = df.select(col("ecommerce"))
    header = ddf[0].keys()
    rows =  [x.values() for x in ddf]
    dddf = tabulate.tabulate(rows, header)
    
    return dddf
```

Whenever I try to forcefully set the type of the ecommerce as MapType I have the error that says that since the original datasource is StringType I can only use the same one as well

Comment: which databricks are you using? azure or aws?

Comment: I am using Azure databricks. What I want to achieve is to basically take the col of the above picture and then make a new table that would have as cols ("detail", "product", "name"...etc ). I thought about simply using string manipulations but it seems to be the overly complicated method so I wanted to see if there was any way for me to extract content differently

Comment: Provide your data in a code format rather than a picture which will be easy to reproduce.

Comment: Please see if it will be possible to use the from_json function and passing the relevant schema...Please refer to the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/sql/language-manual/functions/from_json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have reproduced the above and able to achieve your requirement in this case by using `from_json`, `json_tuple` and `explode`.

This is my sample data with the same format as yours.

[image]

**Code:**

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df2 = df.select(F.json_tuple(df["ecommerce"],"detail")).toDF("detail") \
    .select(F.json_tuple(F.col("detail"),"products")).toDF("products")
print("products : ")
df2.show()

schema = ArrayType(StructType([
    StructField("name", StringType()), 
    StructField("id", StringType()),
    StructField("price", StringType()),
    StructField("brand", StringType()),
    StructField("category", StringType()),
    StructField("variant", StringType())
]))
    
final_df=df2.withColumn("products", F.from_json("products", schema)).select(F.explode("products").alias("products")).select("products.*")
print("Final dataframe : ")
final_df.show()
```

**My Result:**

[image]

Comment: Maybe a bit unrelated, but what if I am to do this on a KAFKA message? By default a kafka message comes with its own schema with the details in json format (in my case) hidden within the "value" column. So far I have to pass in myself the defined schema to be able to extract the content, but would there be a way to let the program figure out naturally what is the best schema for a json formatted input? in a way that is optimized and resource cheap of course